# What happened to the selection and camera toggle buttons in the Scene Collection Window?

Tags: objects, selection-tools, scene, collections, visibility

There used to be all these icons for each of your object in the Scene Collection window. In this picture, there's the visibility, selectability, and a computer and camera icon (not sure what those last two do).

[image]

But in my current project (Blender 2.90), it only shows the eye (visibility toggle).

[image]

Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn them on and off at the top under the Filter button where it says "restriction toggles".

[image: Restrictions]